# Any idea why GetFoldersAsync (WP8.1/C#) is freezing?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await

I'm relatively new to WP8.1 and asynchronous programming and am having an issue with a piece of code I have written/adapted to create a collection of albums, as retrieved from the WP8.1 MusicLibrary

The code is this:

```
    public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Album>> GetAlbums()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Album> returnValue = new ObservableCollection<Album>();
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> loadedMusic = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbumArtist);

        foreach (var file in loadedMusic)
        {
            Album tempAlbum = new Album();
            MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            tempAlbum.Artist = musicProperties.AlbumArtist;
            tempAlbum.Title = musicProperties.Title;
            tempAlbum.ItemImage = "";
            returnValue.Add(tempAlbum);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

The problem is that when the code gets to the GetFoldersAsync line (running on my phone - 8.1 Denim build, currently containing about 30 music albums) it just seems to hang, not returning anything.

Anybody got any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Why don't you try the same with just one or two folders in order to know if the problem is just the time needed to process each one?

Comment: Just tried your code on my computer, its work fine. Did you allow access to Music Library in your manifest?

Comment: That's a partial relief - thanks for trying. I do have music Library in my manifest.
Could it be because this code is in my Shared application location?(attempting to write this as a dual Windows 8/WP8 app)

Comment: I just tried moving the class file to the windows phone area - still no difference. Time to see if extracting the code to a fresh app makes any difference!

Comment: Just tried it in a fresh app and it works - looks like there's something deeper that's causing the issue so I will go delving!